# How is it possible to know the total number of unique metrics in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I've a Prometheus histogram metric for e.g. http_api_end_point_latency_seconds where I am adding 3 labels.
for e.g. http_api_end_point_latency_seconds{uri="api/Home", status="200", authStatus="authorized", le="1.2")

The metric is added in a central place from the app and at any point, we will be having different combinations of the labels leading to different time series.

Question:

We want to monitor the number of different time series that exist at any point in time i.e. we are looking for a unique count of all the unique combination of labels.

Is there a way we can access this using a Prometheus client API?

Answer (score 3):

```
count(http_api_end_point_latency_seconds)
```

would be the easy way, which is the number of time series it has now.